# Change billing address in android pay programatically?

Tags: android, android-pay

I am using android pay in my application, I want to send user default address at the time of payment from my application how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI :
If you implementing android Pay then please don't edit more with shipping address but run time you can add your address at Android Pay and retrieve that address from android pay address list.

Answer (score 1):

From [Android Pay best practices](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/best-practices):

> Android Pay intends to provide you with all of the information you
>   need to complete a transaction, including shipping addresses and other
>   user information stored by Google. An optimal flow would lead from
>   clicking the Android Pay button to the purchase confirmation page to
>   the receipt page riding on the rails of your guest checkout flow. This
>   flow should bypass pages where entering information is redundant. To
>   optimize user experience in this flow, we recommend not asking for
>   user account creation or passwords.
>
> You can use the class gms.identity.intents.Address and the
>   requestUserAddress call to prompt the user to select an address to
>   share with your Android Pay app. This can be useful to facilitate
>   order-ahead use cases, to locate a user's nearest physical store, or
>   to determine whether you can serve the user's chosen address or area.